# Why cannot add instance to a collection of type 'Microsoft.Xaml.Interactivity.BehaviorCollection' (UWP compatibility)?

Tags: c#, xaml, win-universal-app, uwp-xaml

I'm migrating my old project to UWP. And I have some compatibility problem in my xaml code about interaction behaviors. Now the following code won't work

```
  <interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
     <!--//TODO - UWP Compatibility break--> 
    <behaviors:StatusBarBehavior
        BackgroundOpacity="1"
        BackgroundColor="{StaticResource XX.Color.WG}"
        ForegroundColor="{StaticResource XX.Color.TW}"
        IsProgressVisible="{Binding SyncStatusManager.DataTransferInProgress}"
        ProgressText="{Binding LocalizedResources.SyncInProgress, Source={StaticResource LocalizedStrings}}" />

</interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
```

The error information is: **Cannot add instance of type 'xxx.App.Behaviors.StatusBarBehavior' to a collection of type 'Microsoft.Xaml.Interactivity.BehaviorCollection'** any idea why this will   happen?

Comment: That means it doesn't support behavior..  Can you post the control in which you have written

Comment: @Archana Yes it doesn't support behavior, this is at the beginning of the xaml. I tried to install the behavior through NuGet, but failed using this command:  Install-Package Microsoft.Xaml.Behaviors.Uwp.Managed

Comment: Which control are you using